# intercept usb packets in linux before they stary getting handled by the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I want to do a project in which my program prevents all usb packets from getting parsed by the kernel (so that as far as the kernel is concerned they don't exist), take those packets and send them to a remote docker container there I'll allow them to get handled by the kernel

i thought about using kernel module to intercept the packets but I don't really know how and I actually found nothing to help me on the internet, all resources i found point me to usb sniffing rather then usb intercepting

any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You have to **replace** the USB host controller driver for that.

Comment: You want to make a custom implementation of USB/IP? Have you looked at how they do it?